# implementing onClickListener inside a custom ArrayAdapter for a Spinner view

Tags: android, spinner, android-custom-view, clicklistener, custom-arrayadapter

I have the following custom ArrayAdapter -

```java
public class ColorAttributeArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<String> titles;
    private Context context;
    private OnAttributeItemClicked listener;
    private MarketApiCalls marketApiCalls;

    public ColorAttributeArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<String> titles, OnAttributeItemClicked listener) {
        super(context, R.layout.product_attribute_spinner_row_item, R.id.product_attribute_spinner_row_item_textview, titles);
//        super(context, 0,titles);
        this.titles = titles;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_PORTAL_PRODUCTION_URL)
//                .baseUrl(BASE_PORTAL_STAGE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        marketApiCalls = retrofit.create(MarketApiCalls.class);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_attribute_spinner_row_item, parent, false);
        }
        String currentString = titles.get(position);

        //Setting the image color
        ImageView imageView = listItem.findViewById(R.id.product_attribute_spinner_row_item_image_view);
        Map<String, String> htmlStandardColorMap = ColorUtil.getHtmlStandardColorMap();
        if (htmlStandardColorMap.containsKey(currentString)) {
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(htmlStandardColorMap.get(currentString)));
        } else {
            String colorURL = COLORS_API.concat(Uri.encode(currentString, "UTF-8"));
            Picasso.get().load(colorURL).resize(90,90).into(imageView);
        }

        TextView value = listItem.findViewById(R.id.product_attribute_spinner_row_item_textview);
        value.setText(currentString);

        value.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(currentString);
            }
        });

        return listItem;
    }




    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


    public interface OnAttributeItemClicked{
        void onClick(String attributeValue);
    }
}
```

and the following method that creates the Spinners dynamically -

```java
@Override
    public void setProductPurchaseAttributes() {
        selectedProductAttributesMap = selectedProduct.getAttributesList();
        int startingIndex = 6;
        if (!isProductAvailable) return;
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : selectedProductAttributesMap.entrySet()) {

            //creating the linear layout

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            //creating the layout params

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams attributeLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //setting margins

            attributeLayoutParams.setMargins(48,30,48,0);
            textParams.setMargins(0,60,0,0);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(attributeLayoutParams);

            //creating the text view

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(entry.getKey().concat(":"));
            textView.setLayoutParams(textParams);

            //creating the spinner

            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
            List<String> value = entry.getValue();

            //attribute list adapter

            ColorAttributeArrayAdapter adapter = new ColorAttributeArrayAdapter(this, value, attributeValue -> {
                Log.d("itemClicked", attributeValue);
            });
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adding to the linear layout
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
            linearLayout.addView(spinner);
            //adding linear layout to root view
            productDetailsViewGroup.addView(linearLayout, startingIndex);
            startingIndex++;
        }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is that when clicking the view I do get the method being triggered but I am not getting the default behavior of the spinner. 
using 'setOnItemSelectedListener()' on my Spinner isn't a good solution because I need the specific String value that is being hold at that position, and as you can see I am not able to get it from my activity because it is a dynamically created Spinner.

So how can I workaround this issue and add my own behavior to the spinner item click listener?

Comment: I'm not really following why you think you can't use an `OnItemSelectedListener`, but the selected `Spinner` will be passed into that listener's methods as the `AdapterView` parameter, and you can call `getItemAtPosition()` on that to get the selected `String`.

Comment: great - solved. Did not realized I get do 'getItemAtPosition()'. Please comment and I will approve @MikeM.